# Qt - What exactly is QWidget

Tags: c++, qt, qwidget

In the `C++ GUI Programming with Qt 4` book, it mentions in an example in the first chapter that `QWidget` serves as the application's *main window*.

And, on the `Qt Reference Documentation`: http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qwidget.html there is plenty of information about QWidget.

But, what is the baseline? What does QWidget mainly do? When should I think about it?

Comment: Do you understand OOP ? Actually working through a few examples should help you grasp what QWidget is.

Answer (score 7):

One way to think about it is any object that knows how to display itself on the screen is a QWidget (in particular, some subclass of QWidget).

There are some objects like QPicture that represent an image, but a QPicture *by itself* doesn't know how to put itself on the screen. You usually need to use it in combination with a QLabel for instance (which is a kind of QWidget).

Comment: What about the screen `window` itself? Is it a `QWidget`? How can I tell the program that `QWidget` is acting now as a window?

Comment: @user588855: The main window of an application is also a kind of QWidget, one that knows how to draw a window border and interact with the OS-provided functions like close buttons. You can display an arbitrary QWidget with a frame by putting it inside a QMainWindow or similar container.

Comment: I think that's not even needed (certainly not with Qt3) - a `QWidget` that's not part of a window becomes a window in its own right. Mostly an option for lazy programmers, though.

Answer (score 4):

It is an abstract of window objects. Every visible/invisible Qt window-related object inherits from QWidget.

Just consider a vehicle, it is the abstract of cars, trucks and other stuffs.

Comment: Why does the book mention it can act as the `main window`?

Comment: @user: that's because people at Trolltech decided it would be nice if every QWidget could act as a main window.

Comment: @user588855: You can use (almost) the same way driving a truck drive a car.

Answer (score 1):

**Widget** is X11 parlance for something a bit more generic that what other systems call a **control**. A widget can be a pushbutton, a listview, a window, etc...

And BTW, it supposedly comes from *Window Gadget*.

Comment: Qt is not limited to X11, it is cross-platformed.

Comment: @xis19: etymologically, QWidget comes from X11's Widgets.

Comment: I know X11 is rather ancient, but [1920](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=widget) ?!

Comment: @MSalters: didn't know _widget_ existed as a word before the X Window System. So then, _QWidget_ comes from X11's use of _widget_, which itself comes from _widget_ or from _window gadget_ (or, more probably, from both of them).

Answer (score 1):

In windowing systems like X11, there is no difference between a toplevel window and a widget. All are called "windows", and all of them have a parent and children (except the root window, which is usually what the desktop wallpaper is drawn on). So it makes sense that a widget can either be a toplevel window (i.e. a child of the root window) or any other window.